Computing chi-square on text corpora of different sizes
I came across a paper critiquing the calculation of the chi-square statistic for comparing word frequencies across six text corpora of significantly different sizes in a particular text analysis software. The software applies the standard formula:
$$
\chi^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(O_{i} - E_{i})^2}{E_{i}}
$$
Here, $O_{i}$ represents the observed frequency in corpus $i$, and $E_{i}$ is calculated by dividing the total frequency of a word across all six corpora by the total number of words in all corpora and multiplying by the number of words in corpus $i$.
The paper's author critiques this approach, stating:

"Running cross-tabulation does not allow for producing a valid and reliable assessment either. [...] It turns out that the software uses non-normalized absolute frequencies, which does not cause problems only if the text corpora to be compared have equal length."

In this context, the author interprets $O_{i}$ as an absolute frequency and suggests an alternative "normalization" process for calculating $O_{i}$ and $E_{i}$. This involves:

Selecting the smallest corpus as a reference.
Normalizing the observed frequencies of all other corpora by dividing each by the total number of words in the respective corpus and then multiplying by the number of words in the reference corpus.
Computing the expected frequency as the sum of the normalized frequencies across all corpora (including the reference corpus), divided by six (the number of corpora).

QUESTION #1: Is the author right when he claim that the formula used by this software (as described above) does not take into account the various sizes of corpora.
QUESTION #2: Is this normalization approach appropriate for chi-square computation in such cases?

Q1 No!!! Q2 It might make sense to have one corpus as a reference standard, but then if that does make sense you shouldn't include its data in the calculation. From what I know of this field, the smallest corpus is often the most problematic!

Chi-square testing of this kind starts with absolute frequencies. If that is a bad idea, the answer is not some homegrown variant on chi-square.

Both O and E take account of the size of the size of the corpora. There are alternatives to chi-square (e.g. logistic regression) that answer different questions. But the author's proposed method seems to do nothing to help.

Because you (wisely) haven't disclosed the paper, I have no problem suggesting that not only should you avoid that author altogether, but you also should not rely on the journal in which it was published for any statistical advice.  It is not unusual for even prominent institutions to publish statistical garbage, so you must beware.  (I just ran into such a paper published by the American Chemical Society, for instance--but, to their credit, the ACS had slapped a "not peer reviewed" warning on it.)

All statistical people would recognise your formula, but such notation owes more to habit and conformism than to good taste. As a sample statistic, chi-square would be better as say $X^2$, which can be found in the literature. $O$ can be confused by the naive with zero; $E$ is in general the expectation operator; the number of categories might be better as say $k$ not $n$, which more commonly denotes the sample size. Finally, in your case chi-square is a sum over both rows and columns of a two-way table. This comment is pedantry run amok and doesn't affect your interesting question.

Joining the chorus of comments, with some counter-example to prove that the author does not know what he/she is talking about.
Short answer to both your questions: absolutely no. The $\chi^2$ test does take the sample size behind each proportion into account, and that is exactly as it should be.
Just to demonstrate this, let's take the following contingency table (the last row and column are the totals);
$\begin {matrix} 4 & 8 & 12\\ 8 & 4 & 12\\ 12 & 12 & 24\end {matrix}$
The 2 proportions are 33.33% and 66.67% (one is twice the other!). A $\chi^2$ test will return a p-value of .1025, non-significant at the traditional $\alpha=.05$ level. This is because the sample sizes are small, and therefore there is sufficient uncertainty about the observed proportions to not be able to reject the null.
Now, let's just triple the sample size of the 2nd sample, keeping the 2 proportions exactly the same;
$\begin {matrix} 4 & 24 & 28\\ 8 & 12 & 20\\ 12 & 36 & 48\end {matrix}$
The proportions are identical, but now $p=.0425$. Significant. So obviously the sample sizes make a difference. The result would be identical if we had tripled the sample size of the first sample. But based on the author's recommendation, the 2 p-values would be identical (and not significant)...
When a sample has a larger sample size (relative to the others), the uncertainty about its proportion is smaller (just as the uncertainty about its mean, or sd, etc. would be smaller). The $\chi^2$ test takes this into account (as any well constructed statistical test does). What the author suggests amounts to pretending all samples have the same size as the smallest one; this loses all the added information (and precision) provided by the larger sample sizes. This is statistics 101; larger samples are better. But the author throws this away. Simply absurd.
Therefore, also +1 for @whuber suggesting that "not only should you avoid that author altogether, but you also should not rely on the journal in which it was published for any statistical advice".
